# How can all quantum measurement statistics be seen just as projective measurements on pure states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, density-operator

Let $\rho$ be the density matrix for a system and let the POVMs be $\{E_m\}$ such that $\sum_i {E_m} = I$. The probability of getting the outcome $m$ is $\operatorname{Tr}(E_m \rho)$.

The source  I am reading from ( [Semi definite programming to characterize quantum set](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwj3tLCcw9_GAhWLwo4KHeZZApI&url=http%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fabs%2F0803.4290&ei=hpKnVffZG4uFuwTms4mQCQ&usg=AFQjCNF3zLVhjEajXLxoUTwGnJvgiG3A8Q&sig2=kwjbUPc1nkUgISK3KiZ9RQ&bvm=bv.97949915,d.c2E) , section 2.2 second paragraph )  says that the same probabilities of getting the outcomes can be obtained by performing projective measurements on a pure state (there is no restriction given on what the pure state is). That is there exists a pure state $|\phi\rangle$ ( of some arbitary dimension ) and projective opererators $\{P_m\}$ such that for every $m$ , $\langle  \phi | P_m |\phi \rangle = \operatorname{Tr}(E_m\rho)$. To state it more clearly I want to prove that general POVMs can be done as projective measurements on a pure state of a larger dimension Hilbert space.

For more clarity the exact paragraph from the source I mentioned above , which I am trying to prove is

> Any any
>   general measurement on a given Hilbert space can be viewed as a projective measurement
>   on a larger Hilbert space, and any mixed state ρ can be viewed as a subsystem of a larger
>   system in a pure state.

I tried but can't find a way to prove the statement .  I was able to prove that for POVMs for a mixed state $\rho$ can be seen as POVMs for a pure state $|\psi\rangle$ of a larger dimension ( using purification ). But I have no idea oh how to prove that POVMs on a pure state can be seen as projective measurements on some other pure state ( of some other dimension ). I am not even sure if this is the correct way to proceed.

Comment: Projective measurement sutisfies $P=P^{\dagger}$. You want to prove that for any $E_m$ and pure state exist $P=E_m\otimes A$ such that $P=P^{\dagger}$ i.e. $E_m\otimes A=E_m^{\dagger}\otimes A^{\dagger}$ .Thus you need to prove that for any $E_m$ you can find $A$ that sutisfies this relation.

Comment: @Alexander How would this answer the question?  -- Since the comments have been deleted, let me say again that this is answered in Preskill's lecture notes, chapter 3.1.4, "Neumark's theorem".

Comment: Read also my answer here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/184524/what-is-the-difference-between-general-measurement-and-projective-measurement/184540#184540 - if I remember correctly, I also more or less sketched a proof of Naimark's dilation theorem that Norbert Schuch referred to.