# Does the first part of the measurement postulate imply the second?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability, measurement-problem

Common formulations of the general measurement postulate of quantum mechanics have two parts, one establishing the probability of the outcome $m$ corresponding to an observable $M_m$ for a system in an initial state $\left|\psi\right>$:

$$\left|\left|\psi_m\right>\right|^2=p(m) $$

where $\left|\psi_m\right>\equiv M_m\left|\psi\right>$; and a second part specifying the post measurement state of the system given that $m$ is observed.

But is the seond part necessary? Isn't it a consequence of the first part?

The first part establishes a relationship between component norms and probabilities of the form

$$\Vert\left| \psi\right>\Vert_E=\sqrt{\mathbb{P}(E)}$$

where $\Vert\left| \psi\right>\Vert_E$ is the norm of the component of a system $\left| \psi\right>$ corresponding the the occurrence of event $E$, specifically, the postulate states that

$$\Vert\left| \psi\right>\Vert_{O=m\wedge M=M_m}=\sqrt{\mathbb{P}(O=m\wedge M=\psi_m)}$$

where $O$ is the observed outcome and $M$ is the applied observable.

Is this correspondence between norms and probability a general one so that

$$\Vert\left| \psi\right>\Vert_{M=M_m\vert O=m}=\frac{\Vert\left| \psi\right>\Vert_{O=m\wedge M=M_m}}{\sqrt{\mathbb{P}(O=m)}}=\frac{\Vert\left| \psi_m\right>\Vert}{\sqrt{p(m)}}$$

and the second part of the postulate thus follows from the first part (keeping in mind that, by construction, the event $O=m'\wedge M=M_{m''}$ cannot occur for $m'\neq m''$)?

If so, isn't the second part of the postulate entirely unnecessary: establishing this "conditional amplitude" is its only content?

Comment: This seems like a way of formulating the two postulates as one. I know them as "We get an eigenvalue as the measurement value", and "The wavefunction collapses to the projection of the original wavefunction on the eigenspace of the measured eigenvalue". You instead formulate it as "We get an eigenvalue as the measurement value and the wavefunction collapses".

Comment: @Omry: There's no "collapse". That can be dispensed with (that's part of the point here). And your formulation mentions nothing about probabilities, which is the core of the the Born rule (which cannot be dispensed with).

Comment: A minor detail: your expression for $p(m)$ is off.  If you want the probability of measurement, you need to project your state onto the eigenstate corresponding to $m$, and then norm-square.

Comment: @CDCM: I think you've misread: $\left|\psi_m\right>\equiv M_m\left|\psi\right>$, as stated in the question.

Comment: Perhaps, though that equation isn't exactly clear what you're saying.  e.g. I'd be more used to $$p(m)=\lvert\langle \phi_m \lvert \psi \rangle\rvert^2,$$ where $\phi_m$ are defined through the eigenvalue equation for the particular operator, $$\hat{M}\phi_m = \lambda_m \phi_m.$$

Comment: Finally as for the actual question, I think by saying it "should be a consequence of postulate 1", is basically stating the second postulate.  There's no reason to expect that QM systems should behave in such a nice sensible way, so we need to state it as a property/postulate.

Comment: @CDCM That's the question: Does the second part of the postulate have additional information beyond what's required by the the behavior of probabilities for joint and conditional events? The point of the question is that (it seems) if you're keeping track of events correctly, the first part of the postulate (along, of course with its definitions of measurement and the corresponding operators) implies the second.  (Also: I think you're used to projective measurements. That's why I specified [general measurement](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/184524/2540) in the question.)